# Why must SUSY be broken?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, supersymmetry, conservation-laws, symmetry-breaking

**Background**

One usually claims that supersymmetry must be spontaneously broken.
The reasoning is roughly the following:

Since $M^2=P^{\mu}P_{\mu}$ is a casimir operator of the supersymmetry algebra, all the particles in a supermultiplet will have the same mass.
Therefore the electron and the selectron will have same mass, and we would be able to produce selectrons at the accelerators, which nowdays operate at an energy scale of $1 \ Tev >> m_e\approx 0.5 \ MeV$.
But clearly no selectrons are ever seen at the $MeV$ scale.

The standard way to avoid this is to introduce some kind of supersymmetry breaking mechanism, of a similar kind of the Higgs mechanism in the standard model.

**Question**

Is it possible that susy is exact and not broken, but still supersymmetric particles can not produced in reaction of ordinary particles, basically because these reactions would violate the conservation of an extra (not yet known) quantum number?

Why is such a scenario discarded a priori, an so much effort is put into the study of the susy breaking mechanism?

Comment: I thought SUSY couldn't be **spontaneously** broken?

Comment: Usually you can get around conservation of quantum numbers by creating a pair of particles, one with 1 for the quantum number and the other with -1 for it.

Comment: Wouldn't the existence of such a conserved quantum number break SUSY? For example, lets say you assigned "Carta charge" 1 to all the superpartners and Carta charge 0 to all the SM particles and said that only charge neutral interactions could occur at TeV energies, for some reason. But now if I do a supersymmetry transformation, my fields will no longer have definite values of Carta charge. On the other hand, if Carta charge were a good symmetry then I should be able to pick my fields to be eigenstates of the Carta charge. So this is inconsistent.

Comment: @JohnRennie, it seems to me, that Fayet-Iliopoulus mechanism, where they add a term like $\xi D$, breaks SUSY spontaneously due to VEV of the $D$-field.

Comment: @JohnRennie - what you thought wasn't right then. See e.g. these papers http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=spontaneously+broken+supersymmetry&hl=en&lr=&btnG=Search and their citation counts. Global SUSY may be and often is spontaneously broken in a very analogous way to symmetries with the Mexican hat potentials. And local SUSY - in supergravity - may also be broken, which makes the gravitinos "eat" the Goldstinos to gain extra polarizations.

Comment: Otherwise the extra quantum number is often discussed in SUSY - it's called the R-parity (or R-charge when the group is continuous). But you may always satisfy the conservation law by creating the particles in particle-antiparticle pairs, as Brendon pointed out. Most generally, we actually do assume that R-parity is almost exactly or exactly conserved and superpartners have to be created in pairs, indeed. But we may still show that the pair creation would be very likely and because it hasn't seen, we may easily exclude superpartners with masses up to many many GeVs.

Comment: @Andrew, the existence of the charge - it is called R-parity and is equal to $1$ for SM particles and $-1$ for their superpartners (it adds up multiplicatively) - doesn't break SUSY in any way. The supervariation of a state $\psi$ i.e. $Q\psi$ simply has the opposite parity than the original state $\psi$. "Finite SUSY transformations" require Grassmannian parameters ("angles") and those may be formally assigned a negative R-charge, too, so that "finite supersymmetry transformations" of states have the same R-parity as the original states.

Comment: @Andrew - your (wrong) argument could be more generally used to argue that the generators of symmetries can't carry any charges. But that's just always wrong for non-Abelian symmetries in which case the generators are always charged under some other generators - they carry some charges. It's against nothing.

Comment: @LubošMotl you are saying that R-parity "secretly" commutes with SUSY, because the SUSY charges are also charged under R-parity. So naive arguments that R-parity break SUSY are false. Have I understood you correctly? It is confusing that R-parity is NOT an R-symmetry.

Comment: @innisfree, I can't recognize your text as mine, sorry. The Q generators have a negative R-parity, $P_R Q P_R^{-1}=-Q$, so they anticommute with each other, but this doesn't imply any violation of either of these two symmetries. A symmetry is violated or not preserved if it refuses to commute with the Hamiltonian. The symmetries' mutual commuting or anticommuting or non-commuting is irrelevant for their being a symmetry.

Comment: @lubos ah thanks, yes i am writing silly things! but i still have a final point of confusion, on p55 of his SUSY primer, Martin writes that R-parity "...secretly does commute with SUSY", what does he mean? Just that a superfield has a well-defined R-parity? http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-ph/9709356v6.pdf

Comment: He probably means that if you remove $2s$ from the exponent in 6.2.5, you get an R-parity-like operator that commutes with Q, so the anticommutation isn't any big deal that would make it nontrivial. He also wants to say that the R-parity coincidence with the R-symmetry modulo 2 is an accident sort of and that the R-parity doesn't need to make it possible to define a whole R-symmetry for that.

Answer (score -4):

If there is a person that writes beautiful historical reviews about subjects related to physics then that person is Ed. Witten... because of this, I quote here these papers where you may find information about SUSY breaking mechanisms, dynamical breaking and mainly how susy is different from "ordinary symmetries".
http://inspirehep.net/record/10634?ln=en

If you read that paper carefully, and maybe some papers about origins of susy you may even find hints for why susy is not real at all... but that's up to your ability to see things not stated directly ;)

Comment: Downvoted, since I believe you answer and the article you cited don't actually answer the question.
Sorry